# jQuery button click function toggles both sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, slidetoggle

When I click one of these two buttons it toggles both the #hide and the .contact p at the same time. I tried adding a class to the ("button") selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").hide();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#hide").slideToggle("display");
   });

  $("#contact p").hide();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#contact p").slideToggle("display");
   });
});
```

https://codepen.io/Shalise/pen/BmmEQJ/

Comment: add all relevant code in OP use `<>` instead of an external link

Comment: Yes, it toggles both, because you've written it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're querying $("button") which grabs an element. You will either want to query a class or an id. For example I added an id of #btn1 and #btn2 to two buttons respectively. Below is modified JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").hide();
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#hide").slideToggle("display");
   });

  $("#contact p").hide();
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#contact p").slideToggle("display");
   });
});
```

Comment: This fixed it, thank you! I feel like I tried this but probably had a small error that led me to believe it wasn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You add both functions to all buttons. That's why both functions where triggerd when you click any button.

As you say: Add a `class` or a `id` to the buttons to tell them apart and only add one function to each button

**HTML**

```
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").hide();
  $("button#first").click(function(){
    $("#hide").slideToggle("display");
  });

  $("#contact p").hide();
  $("button#second").click(function(){
    $("#contact p").slideToggle("display");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use separate class or id in every button. ex:
**HTML**

```
<button class="button-1">First</button>
<button class="button-2">Second</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").hide();
  $("button.button-1").click(function(){
      $("#hide").slideToggle("display");
  });

  $("#contact p").hide();
  $("button.button-2").click(function(){
     $("#contact p").slideToggle("display");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to hide those elements, you can add a class for example a class="hidden" and style it display: none instead of using jQuery hide method.
2. You're using a general button selector, if you have a specific id for each of those buttons, you can target them specifically.
3. Here is a good resource for using slideToggle: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/